# Localization using angular translate

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angular-translate

I am using Angular-Translate library for localization in angularJS.

My requirement is I want to keep single module/controller and call there methods/controller method from number of pages. Project consists of standard directory structure as follows:

- Languages

  - en-US

    - Home.json
    - Contacts.json
  - fr-FR

    - Home.json
    - Contacts.json

These all .json files have there respective html and partial html also. Also, I do not want to provide hard coded path; based on the html(view) rendered and selected language it should pick up the .json file .

So, what approach should be taken ?

Answer (score 0):

Let me try and propose you an alternative:

you can organize your file as

```
en.json:

    { 
      "Home": {
       "key1": "Value one",
       ...
      },
      "Contacts": {...},
      ...
    }
```